# I need a very flexible time regex

Tags: .net, regex, parsing, datetime

I’m looking to create a regex for these patterns:

```
[num] [am]
[num] [pm]
[num] [-] [num]
[num] [:] [num]
```

with or w/o spaces

It’s to determine if there is a time in a sentence. Ideally, it would actually parse out the time. The sentences would be like:

```
“This event is at 9am at…”
“Blues, 5:30, pressroom..”
“Meet at 5pm!”
“All night 9-8 rockin’ it!”
```

My project is in .NET in case it's relevant.

Comment: Good luck with that.

Comment: Normally, even those bad at regexes, attempt _something_ that may or may not work..., but... have you _tried_ anything?

Comment: Also, consider _"divide at a ratio of 1:12"_ , _"If I eat 5 am I then greedy?"_ (yeah, I don't trust people to put a comma in there), loose matching  = expect false positives. Depends on your actual data of course.

Comment: I know it won't be perfect and that's alright. Multiple regexes is fine, can someone help me figure out what those regexes would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your definition, I think something like this is about as good as you can do:

```
"\\b(1[012]|[1-9])(\\s?(am|pm)|:[0-5][0-9]|-(1[012]|[1-9]))\\b"
```

This requires that an hour be between 1-12 and minutes be 0-59.  It also requires word boundaries around the time.  It doesn't allow spaces around dashes or colons.

Nevertheless, you are going to get a lot of false positives by definition, especially with your `[num]-[num]` format, which looks a lot like dates and other stuff.

Tested [here](http://regexpal.com/). I didn't find a specific .NET tester, but I think it is all standard.

Comment: This is to parse specific calendar events. It's a safe gamble to assume it's time. Thanks for this regex. I'm picking it apart now.

Comment: This was great. I adjusted it to: \b(1[012]|[1-9])(\s?(am|pm)|:[0-5][0-9]|\s?-\s?(1[012]|[1-9]))\b, which matches a ton of cases. With this as a base, I can adjust as needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than have one flexible regexp, I would prefer multiple regexps (one for each type of pattern you want to match, most likely), and apply each until you get a match. Note you can use this approach to identify ambiguous time specifications.

This approach is a lot easier to code and maintain (in the future you may want more time formats, and it's trivial to add a new specific regexp rather than modify an already complex/flexible regexp).

Comment: That's fine, but what would those regexes be?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple to build a regex from that "grammar", have [a look at RegExes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)!

```
/(\d{1,2})\s*([:-]\s(\d{1,2})|am|pm)/
```

I've limited your numbers to be until 2 chars long, you might omit that as you probably would look whether the time is in a valid range anyway. To parse the matched string, you can extract the matching groups from the result.

Comment: That looks promising. I'm reading through the RegExes tutorial. I might just have to bake this myself.

Comment: They also have a [chapter on regexes in .NET](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html), which you may find interesting. Especially the section on escaping backslashes is notable :-)